# Using Index/Match Between Two Sheets Returns #SPILL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working in a spreadsheet that contains two sheets. Sheet 1 has a table that contains rows of Purchase Order numbers and columns for each month that house financial data below the headers. The table was imported from another Excel workbook.

Sheet 2 has a column of Purchase Orders that are listed in a different order than Sheet 1, so I am using Index/Match to rearrange the data. I used the formula below, but it just returns the #SPILL error. I've spent a couple days working on fixes and can't seem to get anywhere.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1[23-Apr], MATCH(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2[PO'#],0))
```

Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating a full column with `Sheet2!A:A`  so you would need to put this in row 1 of an empty column.   This is going to return errors where ever there are blanks.

Instead filter the column before putting it in the MATCH.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1[23-Apr], MATCH(FILTER(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!A:A<>""),Sheet2[PO'#],0))
```

This assumes that the number of rows in `Sheet2[PO'#]` matches that of `Sheet1[23-Apr]`, otherwise you risk the relative reference returning from the MATCH to exceed the rows in the INDEX range.

Comment: this did the trick. thank you very much!